# Are all names identifiers?

Tags: java, jls

In the Java Language Specification 6.2 [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2)

Here is the following code example:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = System.out.getClass();
        System.out.println(c.toString().length() +
                           args[0].length() + args.length);
    }
}
```

And it states:

> the identifiers Test, main, and the first occurrences of args and c are not names. Rather, they are used in declarations to specify the names of the declared entities. The names String, Class, System.out.getClass, System.out.println, c.toString, args, and args.length appear in the example.

But are the names like Class and String also identifiers? What is an identifier exactly?

Comment: The use of "name" here seems strange to me.  I assume that by _name_ they mean _named reference_, in which case it would make sense to exclude `Test`, `main`, and the first occurrences of `args` and `c` (because declarations != references).  All named references and declarations are identifiers, so yes, `Class` and `String` are identifiers.

Comment: This is the same interpretation that I make. I don't know how I missed this but further down it says: "One might wonder why these kinds of expression use an identifier rather than a simple name, which is after all just an identifier." So it seems like names are also identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An identifier is a type of a token. From the specification of the [lexical structure of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> ## 3.8. Identifiers
>
> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>
> ```
> Identifier:
>     IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
>
> IdentifierChars:
>     JavaLetter
>     IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit
>
>  JavaLetter:
>      any Unicode character that is a Java letter (see below)
>
>  JavaLetterOrDigit:
>      any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit (see below)
> ```
>
> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int) returns true.
>
> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int) returns true.
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.
>
> The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039).
>
> Letters and digits may be drawn from the entire Unicode character set,
>   which supports most writing scripts in use in the world today,
>   including the large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. This
>   allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are
>   written in their native languages.
>
> An identifier cannot have the same spelling (Unicode character
>   sequence) as a keyword (§3.9), boolean literal (§3.10.3), or the null
>   literal (§3.10.7), or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: So your interpretation is that names are also identifiers?

Comment: You could say that. As defined in the JLS, "names" are specified using identifiers. Not all identifiers specify "names" though.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your 2nd question:

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/08.html

> Identifiers are the names of variables, methods, classes, packages and
>   interfaces. Unlike literals they are not the things themselves, just
>   ways of referring to them.

Answer (score 0):

An identifier is a **user defined symbol**.

It allows the compiler to differentiate between bindings to objects of the same type in the symbol table.